# React re-render auth route based on localstorage deletion

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a protected route in my react app and I need it to listen for when the localstorage item gets deleted. If the item is deleted, go back to the login page. Right now I just check for if the item exists but it doesnt re render the component when the localstorage item gets deleted. Ive tried using libraries like `react-use-localstorage` but it doesnt notify me when the item is deleted only when it is changed. This is the file:

```
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const [authToken] = useLocalStorage(AUTH_TOKEN);

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        authToken ? (
          <Layout>
            <Component {...props} />
          </Layout>
        ) : 
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: '/login',
              }}
            />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

The reason why I need it to do this is because, if there is nothing in localstorage, the component still renders for a quick second before redirecting to login.

Edit.
This is where the error is. In the INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR case is. I am using graphql to check if user is authenticated. Using history.push('/login') doesnt redirect me straight away, it shows an error flash for a quick second before redirecting me.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    onError(({ graphQLErrors, operation, forward }) => {
      if (graphQLErrors) {
        graphQLErrors.forEach(err => {
          console.log(err);
          switch (err.extensions.code) {
            case 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR':
              if (err.path && err.path[0] === 'updateToken') {
                removeItem(AUTH_TOKEN);
                // history.push('/login');
              }
              return forward(operation);
            default:
              return forward(operation);
          }
        });
      }
    }),
    requestLink,
    uploadLink,
  ]),
  cache,
});
```

These are the only 2 places when i am handling redirecting around this issue. When I delete the localstorage item manually in chrome, it redirects me but if the token expires, it shows a quick error message first before redirecting me.

Comment: Could you provide a full code example?  It sounds like you are setting localstorage but the state within your hook hasn't updated yet when you render.  If you provide details we can figure out where the logic gap is.

Comment: When I delete the localstorage item maually in chrome, it redirects me but if the token is expired it shows a quick error message first, then redirects me

Comment: @jack.benson i added code to the edit

Comment: I've added a working example with approximately what you posted here.  Could you add details to that so we can replicate your functionality?  https://codesandbox.io/s/red-http-gtbq1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @jack.benson thats similar to what ive had i made changes to it

Comment: Do you have a link to your modified version?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-mccarthy-3eqk5?file=/src/App.js @jack.benson

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to changes in the localStorage. Something like a storage event should do the trick. You'll receive an event, and you can check if your AUTH_TOKEN is still present in the localStorage. If not, you can re-route immediately.

Here's the MDN link for this:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event
You'll have to create a new hook for this as this is a direct web API. Or find a package for this.